# Do Event Macros have a self-reference capacity like Me or This?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to have a series of buttons that after being clicked, use a macro to create a TempVar containing the caption of the button.
I really don't want to have to use VBA, as everything else in the form is a macro.

At the moment, I have a macro that creates a Tempvar using this selector:

```
[Command5].[Caption]
```

However, I'd like to replace [Command5] with something Me or This. Then I could copy & paste the button without having to open each new one and update the control name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `[Screen].[ActiveControl]` method. Set temporary variable like-

```
[Screen].[ActiveControl].[Caption]
```

Then use that ***tempvar*** for further action. See the below screenshot for better picture.

[image]

Comment: Note that this is error-prone, when other code triggers the event you can get either the wrong control or no control at all. Generally, when attempting to reuse code to handle events, it's best to use VBA and put that code in a function or class.

Comment: @ErikA Yes, that depends on use of control. I generally prefer coding to macro controller.